# QGIS 2.2.0 Update column with another layer

Tags: qgis-2

I've got 2 layers : the first one with points, the second one with polygones (their ID). I created a new column in the first layer, and I want to update it with the ID of the polygone that contains the point.
I hope I'm clear !
It seems to be a basic issue, but I spend a large part of the day surching for the answer, in vain... Thanks a lot for the incoming answer!

Comment: That is called a spatial join. Vector > Data Management > Join Attributes by Location.

Comment: I did as you suggested, it worked perfectly. Thanks